# Prevent laptop from connecting to WLAN channels

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, bluetooth

I recently bought an MSI laptop, and I found this label on the box:

[image: EU restrictions label]

I assume this has something to do with the laptop's radio emitters (judging by the WLAN and Bluetooth labels), but the instruction manual goes into no detail as to what "restrictions" I should be aware of.

The USA and EU have different allowed channels and frequencies on the WLAN 5G network. However, the allowed frequencies regarding Bluetooth and 2.4G are the same. For reference, Bluetooth operates on 2400 and 2483.5 MHz, which is allowed in the EU [frequency allocation chart](http://www.ancom.org.ro/uploads/links_files/form_ram_extras%20din%20reglementari%20internationale%20CEPT%20-%20tabelul%20comun%20european.pdf).

How do I prevent my laptop from attempting to connect to WLAN channels that are banned in the EU but allowed in the USA (channels 34, 38, 42 to name a few, check [this chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#5_GHz_(802.11a/h/j/n/ac/ax)))? This may become necessary if I attempt a Wi-Fi direct connection, and the laptop can not rely on an access point for interference information ([Dynamic Frequency Selection](http://wifinigel.blogspot.com/2018/05/the-5ghz-problem-for-wi-fi-networks-dfs.html)).

Comment: My guess (IANAL) is that this is similar to FCC requirement that a device not emit harmful interference, and must accept any interference it receives (ie it does not jam other devices, and can be jammed by another party like law enforcement).

Comment: It most likely refers to restrictions on allowed channels / frequencies. The US and Europe differ on what is allowed and what isn't, and depending on where your laptop was sold it may be to FCC or European spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Wi-Fi radio does the right thing for you automatically.

Most Wi-Fi chipsets will do a safe scan at boot/wake time, until they see any AP's beacons or probe responses which contain a country code information element. Then they will set that country as their regulatory domain until they get powered off and back on the next time.

The safe scans involve active scans on globally safe channels, and passive silent listening on channels that are restricted in any region.

Your card may have a default regulatory profile based on the country or region it was sold in, and it might let you customize that via an advanced driver property. These only come into play if you are setting the card to act as an AP, and it's not in range of any other APs with country code information elements.

Laptop Wi-Fi cards are too low-power to cause any noticeable interference more than say 50m away anyway, so no one who cares is likely to even be able to detect a misbehaving laptop card. They're certainly not going to be inconvenienced by your signal enough to bother calling the authorities over it, and the authorities would probably just laugh them off. To actually get in regulatory/legal trouble for misusing the 2.4GHz or 5GHz band, you'd probably have to start setting up high power outdoor long range equipment.